# Calculate when is convenient taking advantage of sorting in filtering arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filter, time-complexity

I'm trying to optimize my FilterArray function so I've thought to use the sorted column (when available).

The original function loops through all items in the array, make comparison in various columns and build the resulting array.

In this new version, I want to reduce the number of main loop's iterations by finding the first and last valid row in the sorted column, so I've added a first loop that:

- Compare the value in the sorted column and lowest acceptable limit
- When the first valid row is founded, store it and start searching for high limit
- If high limit is founded or upper bound is reached, exit the loop
- Pass to the main loop the valid range in which search

This new approach works and can reduce a lot the time of execution, but not always.
From an intuitive point of view, I can understand that it is an optimization when the first loop reduces at least ?a bit? the number of loops of the main loop.. But..

**1- How can I calculate when is actually convenient to use it?**

I'm really not familiar with the concept of complexity, but for the bit I was able to understand this new approach is not reducing the magnitude of complexity, but in those cases where the first loop works well the running time is sensibly lower...

**2- What kind of optimization is this?** Sorry if this is not a good question..

In this first piece of code, I'm assuming that the order of sortedColumn is ascending because this is the only way in which variable's name make sense (I've written first for ascending order and then adjusted for both the orders).

You'll find the correct code below.

You'll find the new code that search in sorted column between '---------------

Thank you in advance!

This is new OOP version.. Class ArrayFilter

```
Option Explicit

Private pColumnsToReturn    As Variant
Private pFiltersCollection  As Collection
Private pPartialMatchColl   As Collection

Private Enum filterType
    negativeMatch = -1
    exactMatch = 0
    isBetween = 1
    contains = 2
End Enum

Public Property Let ColumnsToReturn(arr As Variant)
    pColumnsToReturn = arr
End Property

Public Property Get Filters() As Collection
    Set Filters = pFiltersCollection
End Property

Public Sub IncludeEquals(ByRef equalTo As Variant, ByRef inColumn As Long, _
                         Optional ByRef isCaseSensitive As Boolean = False)

    If inColumn > -1 Then

        Dim thisFilter              As Collection
        Dim thisFilterType          As filterType

        Set thisFilter = New Collection
        thisFilterType = exactMatch

        With thisFilter
            .Add thisFilterType
            .Add inColumn
            .Add IIf(isCaseSensitive, equalTo, LCase(equalTo))
            .Add isCaseSensitive
        End With

        If pFiltersCollection Is Nothing Then Set pFiltersCollection = New Collection

        pFiltersCollection.Add thisFilter
        Set thisFilter = Nothing

    End If

End Sub

Public Sub ExcludeEquals(ByRef equalTo As Variant, ByRef inColumn As Long, _
                         Optional ByRef isCaseSensitive As Boolean = False)

    If inColumn > -1 Then

        Dim thisFilter              As Collection
        Dim thisFilterType          As filterType

        Set thisFilter = New Collection
        thisFilterType = negativeMatch

        With thisFilter
            .Add thisFilterType
            .Add inColumn
            .Add IIf(isCaseSensitive, equalTo, LCase(equalTo))
            .Add isCaseSensitive
        End With

        If pFiltersCollection Is Nothing Then Set pFiltersCollection = New Collection

        pFiltersCollection.Add thisFilter
        Set thisFilter = Nothing

    End If

End Sub

Public Sub IncludeBetween(ByRef lowLimit As Variant, ByRef highLimit As Variant, ByRef inColumn As Long)

    If inColumn > -1 Then

        Dim thisFilter              As Collection
        Dim thisFilterType          As filterType

        Set thisFilter = New Collection
        thisFilterType = isBetween

        With thisFilter
            .Add thisFilterType
            .Add inColumn
            .Add lowLimit
            .Add highLimit
        End With

        If pFiltersCollection Is Nothing Then Set pFiltersCollection = New Collection

        pFiltersCollection.Add thisFilter
        Set thisFilter = Nothing

    End If

End Sub

Public Sub IncludeIfContain(ByRef substring As String, Optional ByRef inColumns As Variant = 1)

    If IsArray(inColumns) Or IsNumeric(inColumns) Then

        Dim thisFilterType          As filterType

        Set pPartialMatchColl = New Collection
        thisFilterType = contains

        With pPartialMatchColl
            .Add thisFilterType
            .Add inColumns
            .Add substring
        End With

    End If

End Sub

Public Sub ApplyTo(ByRef originalArray As Variant)

    If Not IsArray(originalArray) Then Exit Sub

    Dim firstRow                    As Long
    Dim lastRow                     As Long
    Dim firstColumn                 As Long
    Dim lastColumn                  As Long
    Dim row                         As Long
    Dim col                         As Long
    Dim arrayOfColumnToReturn       As Variant
    Dim partialMatchColumnsArray    As Variant
    Dim result                      As Variant

    result = -1
    arrayOfColumnToReturn = pColumnsToReturn
    If Not pPartialMatchColl Is Nothing Then partialMatchColumnsArray = pPartialMatchColl(2)

    ' If the caller don't pass the array of column to return
    ' create an array with all the columns and preserve the order
    If Not IsArray(arrayOfColumnToReturn) Then
        ReDim arrayOfColumnToReturn(LBound(originalArray, 2) To UBound(originalArray, 2))
        For col = LBound(originalArray, 2) To UBound(originalArray, 2)
            arrayOfColumnToReturn(col) = col
        Next col
    End If

    ' If the caller don't pass an array for partial match
    ' check if it pass the special value 1, if true the
    ' partial match will be performed on values in columns to return
    If Not IsArray(partialMatchColumnsArray) Then
        If partialMatchColumnsArray = 1 Then partialMatchColumnsArray = arrayOfColumnToReturn
    End If

    firstRow = LBound(originalArray, 1)
    lastRow = UBound(originalArray, 1)

    ' main loop
    Dim keepCount           As Long
    Dim filter              As Variant
    Dim currentFilterType   As filterType

    ReDim arrayOfRowsToKeep(lastRow - firstRow + 1) As Variant
    keepCount = 0

    For row = firstRow To lastRow

        ' exact, excluse and between checks
        If Not Me.Filters Is Nothing Then
            For Each filter In Me.Filters
                currentFilterType = filter(1)
                Select Case currentFilterType
                    Case negativeMatch
                        If filter(4) Then
                            If originalArray(row, filter(2)) = filter(3) Then GoTo Skip
                        Else
                            If LCase(originalArray(row, filter(2))) = filter(3) Then GoTo Skip
                        End If
                    Case exactMatch
                        If filter(4) Then
                            If originalArray(row, filter(2)) <> filter(3) Then GoTo Skip
                        Else
                            If LCase(originalArray(row, filter(2))) <> filter(3) Then GoTo Skip
                        End If
                    Case isBetween
                        If originalArray(row, filter(2)) < filter(3) _
                        Or originalArray(row, filter(2)) > filter(4) Then GoTo Skip
                End Select
            Next filter
        End If

        ' partial match check
        If Not pPartialMatchColl Is Nothing Then
            If IsArray(partialMatchColumnsArray) Then
                For col = LBound(partialMatchColumnsArray) To UBound(partialMatchColumnsArray)
                    If InStr(1, originalArray(row, partialMatchColumnsArray(col)), pPartialMatchColl(3), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        GoTo Keep
                    End If
                Next
                GoTo Skip
            End If
        End If
Keep:
        arrayOfRowsToKeep(keepCount) = row
        keepCount = keepCount + 1
Skip:
    Next row

    ' create results array
    If keepCount > 0 Then

        firstRow = LBound(originalArray, 1)
        lastRow = LBound(originalArray, 1) + keepCount - 1
        firstColumn = LBound(originalArray, 2)
        lastColumn = LBound(originalArray, 2) + UBound(arrayOfColumnToReturn) - LBound(arrayOfColumnToReturn)

        ReDim result(firstRow To lastRow, firstColumn To lastColumn)

        For row = firstRow To lastRow
            For col = firstColumn To lastColumn
                result(row, col) = originalArray(arrayOfRowsToKeep(row - firstRow), arrayOfColumnToReturn(col - firstColumn + LBound(arrayOfColumnToReturn)))
            Next col
        Next row

    End If

    originalArray = result
    If IsArray(result) Then Erase result

End Sub
```

Code with both sorting orders:

```
Function FilterArray(ByVal originalArray As Variant, _
                    Optional arrayOfColumnToReturn As Variant, _
                    Optional sortedColumn As Integer = -1, Optional IsAscendingSorted As Boolean, Optional sortedColumnLowValue As Variant, Optional sortedColumnHighValue As Variant, _
                    Optional firstExactMatchColumn As Integer = -1, Optional firstExactMatchValue As Variant, _
                    Optional secondExactMatchColumn As Integer = -1, Optional secondExactMatchValue As Variant, _
                    Optional thirdExactMatchColumn As Integer = -1, Optional thirdExactMatchValue As Variant, _
                    Optional firstColumnToExclude As Integer = -1, Optional firstValueToExclude As Variant, _
                    Optional secondColumnToExclude As Integer = -1, Optional secondValueToExclude As Variant, _
                    Optional thirdColumnToExclude As Integer = -1, Optional thirdValueToExclude As Variant, _
                    Optional firstColumnIsBetween As Integer = -1, Optional firstLowValue As Variant, Optional firstHighValue As Variant, _
                    Optional secondColumnIsBetween As Integer = -1, Optional secondLowValue As Variant, Optional secondHighValue As Variant, _
                    Optional thirdColumnIsBetween As Integer = -1, Optional thirdLowValue As Variant, Optional thirdHighValue As Variant, _
                    Optional partialMatchColumnsArray As Variant = -1, Optional partialMatchValue As Variant) As Variant

    FilterArray = -1

    If Not IsArray(originalArray) Then Exit Function

    Dim firstRow            As Long
    Dim lastRow             As Long
    Dim firstColumn         As Long
    Dim lastColumn          As Long
    Dim row                 As Long
    Dim col                 As Long
    Dim filteredArrayRow    As Long
    Dim partialCol          As Long

    ' If the caller don't pass the array of column to return I create an array with all the columns and I preserve the order
    If Not IsArray(arrayOfColumnToReturn) Then
        ReDim arrayOfColumnToReturn(LBound(originalArray, 2) To UBound(originalArray, 2))
        For col = LBound(originalArray, 2) To UBound(originalArray, 2)
            arrayOfColumnToReturn(col) = col
        Next col
    End If

    firstRow = LBound(originalArray, 1)
    lastRow = UBound(originalArray, 1)
    firstColumn = LBound(arrayOfColumnToReturn)
    lastColumn = UBound(arrayOfColumnToReturn)

    ' If the caller don't pass an array for partial match check if it pass the special value 1, if true the partial macth will be performed on values in columns to return
    If Not IsArray(partialMatchColumnsArray) Then
        If partialMatchColumnsArray = 1 Then partialMatchColumnsArray = arrayOfColumnToReturn
    End If

    ReDim tempFilteredArray(firstColumn To lastColumn, firstRow To firstRow) As Variant

    filteredArrayRow = firstRow - 1
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    If sortedColumn > -1 Then

        Dim ImSearchingForLowLine   As Boolean
        Dim lowRow                  As Long
        Dim highRow                 As Long

        highRow = IIf(IsAscendingSorted, lastRow, firstRow) 'Set default values that won't allow to run the Main loop if First loop don't change them.
        lowRow = IIf(IsAscendingSorted, lastRow + 1, firstRow - 1)

        ImSearchingForLowLine = True

        'First loop
        'Depending from the sorting order, loop from FirstToLast or LastToFirst
        For row = IIf(IsAscendingSorted, firstRow, lastRow) To IIf(IsAscendingSorted, lastRow, firstRow) Step IIf(IsAscendingSorted, 1, -1)
            If ImSearchingForLowLine Then
                If originalArray(row, sortedColumn) < sortedColumnLowValue Then
                    GoTo NextRow
                Else
                    'This second check is needed to avoid false positive.
                    If originalArray(row, sortedColumn) <= sortedColumnHighValue Then
                        'Now I've found the first valid row, I store it and start search for last valid row
                        lowRow = row
                        ImSearchingForLowLine = False
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                If originalArray(row, sortedColumn) > sortedColumnHighValue Then
                    'Now row is the first invalid row.
                    highRow = row + IIf(IsAscendingSorted, -1, 1)
                    Exit For
                Else
                    GoTo NextRow
                End If
            End If
NextRow:
        Next row
        firstRow = IIf(IsAscendingSorted, lowRow, highRow)
        lastRow = IIf(IsAscendingSorted, highRow, lowRow)
    End If
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Main Loop
    For row = firstRow To lastRow

        ' Start Exact Match check
        If firstExactMatchColumn > -1 Then
            If LCase(originalArray(row, firstExactMatchColumn)) <> LCase(firstExactMatchValue) Then GoTo SkipRow
        End If
        If secondExactMatchColumn > -1 Then
            If LCase(originalArray(row, secondExactMatchColumn)) <> LCase(secondExactMatchValue) Then GoTo SkipRow
        End If
        If thirdExactMatchColumn > -1 Then
            If LCase(originalArray(row, thirdExactMatchColumn)) <> LCase(thirdExactMatchValue) Then GoTo SkipRow
        End If
        ' End Exact Match check

        ' Start Negative Match check
        If firstColumnToExclude > -1 Then
            If LCase(originalArray(row, firstColumnToExclude)) = LCase(firstValueToExclude) Then GoTo SkipRow
        End If
        If secondColumnToExclude > -1 Then
            If LCase(originalArray(row, secondColumnToExclude)) = LCase(secondValueToExclude) Then GoTo SkipRow
        End If
        If thirdColumnToExclude > -1 Then
            If LCase(originalArray(row, thirdColumnToExclude)) = LCase(thirdValueToExclude) Then GoTo SkipRow
        End If
        ' End Negative Match check

        ' Start isBetween check
        If firstColumnIsBetween > -1 Then
            If originalArray(row, firstColumnIsBetween) < firstLowValue Or originalArray(row, firstColumnIsBetween) > firstHighValue Then GoTo SkipRow
        End If
        If secondColumnIsBetween > -1 Then
            If originalArray(row, secondColumnIsBetween) < secondLowValue Or originalArray(row, secondColumnIsBetween) > secondHighValue Then GoTo SkipRow
        End If
        If thirdColumnIsBetween > -1 Then
            If originalArray(row, thirdColumnIsBetween) < thirdLowValue Or originalArray(row, thirdColumnIsBetween) < thirdHighValue Then GoTo SkipRow
        End If
        ' End isBetween check

        ' Start partial match check
        If IsArray(partialMatchColumnsArray) Then
            For partialCol = LBound(partialMatchColumnsArray) To UBound(partialMatchColumnsArray)
                If InStr(1, originalArray(row, partialMatchColumnsArray(partialCol)), partialMatchValue, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    GoTo WriteRow
                End If
            Next partialCol
            GoTo SkipRow
        End If
        ' End partial match check
WriteRow:
        ' Writing data in the filtered array
        filteredArrayRow = filteredArrayRow + 1
        ReDim Preserve tempFilteredArray(firstColumn To lastColumn, LBound(tempFilteredArray, 1) To filteredArrayRow)

        For col = firstColumn To lastColumn
            tempFilteredArray(col, filteredArrayRow) = originalArray(row, arrayOfColumnToReturn(col))
        Next col
SkipRow:
    Next row

    If filteredArrayRow > LBound(tempFilteredArray, 1) - 1 Then
        FilterArray = InvertiMatrice(tempFilteredArray) 'This is similar to Application.Transpose
    End If

    Erase originalArray
    Erase arrayOfColumnToReturn
    If IsArray(partialMatchColumnsArray) Then Erase partialMatchColumnsArray
    If IsArray(tempFilteredArray) Then Erase tempFilteredArray

End Function
```

As required, this is the code of InvertiMatrice function. The purpose is to invert rows and columns in a two dimensional array.

```
Function InvertiMatrice(originalArray As Variant) As Variant

    InvertiMatrice = -1
    If Not IsArray(originalArray) Then Exit Function

    Dim row             As Long
    Dim column          As Long
    Dim firstRow        As Long
    Dim lastRow         As Long
    Dim firstColumn     As Long
    Dim lastColumn      As Long

    firstRow = LBound(originalArray, 1)
    firstColumn = LBound(originalArray, 2)
    lastRow = UBound(originalArray, 1)
    lastColumn = UBound(originalArray, 2)

    ReDim tempArray(firstColumn To lastColumn, firstRow To lastRow) As Variant

    For row = firstColumn To lastColumn
        For column = firstRow To lastRow
            tempArray(row, column) = originalArray(column, row)
        Next column
    Next row

    InvertiMatrice = tempArray

    Erase originalArray
    Erase tempArray

End Function
```

Comment: @CDP1802 Hi, just added..

Comment: The idea is to maintain applications usable over years of data collecting.. From 30k to 150k rows and 25-30 columns..

Comment: Forget last comment I realised my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than building the tempFilteredArray one row at a time and incurring 
the time penalty of redimensioning the array, this code works on the principle of keeping
the row numbers in a single dimension array (called arKeep) and an incrementing counter KeepCount.
At the end dimension the tempFilteredArray to the size of KeepCount and fill using the row numbers in arKeep
as pointers back to the originalArray.

The other change is to move operation like LCase(firstExactMatchValue) outside the loop and do them once.

Hope this helps

```
Function FilterArray2(ByVal originalArray As Variant, _
    Optional arrayOfColumnToReturn As Variant, _
    Optional sortedColumn As Integer = -1, Optional IsAscendingSorted As Boolean, Optional sortedColumnLowValue As Variant, Optional sortedColumnHighValue As Variant, _
    Optional firstExactMatchColumn As Integer = -1, Optional firstExactMatchValue As Variant, _
    Optional secondExactMatchColumn As Integer = -1, Optional secondExactMatchValue As Variant, _
    Optional thirdExactMatchColumn As Integer = -1, Optional thirdExactMatchValue As Variant, _
    Optional firstColumnToExclude As Integer = -1, Optional firstValueToExclude As Variant, _
    Optional secondColumnToExclude As Integer = -1, Optional secondValueToExclude As Variant, _
    Optional thirdColumnToExclude As Integer = -1, Optional thirdValueToExclude As Variant, _
    Optional firstColumnIsBetween As Integer = -1, Optional firstLowValue As Variant, Optional firstHighValue As Variant, _
    Optional secondColumnIsBetween As Integer = -1, Optional secondLowValue As Variant, Optional secondHighValue As Variant, _
    Optional thirdColumnIsBetween As Integer = -1, Optional thirdLowValue As Variant, Optional thirdHighValue As Variant, _
    Optional partialMatchColumnsArray As Variant = -1, Optional partialMatchValue As Variant) As Variant

    If Not IsArray(originalArray) Then Exit Function

    ' If the caller don't pass the array of column to return
    ' create an array with all the columns to preserve the order
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, ref As Variant, t0 As Single
    t0 = Timer
    ref = arrayOfColumnToReturn
    If Not IsArray(ref) Then
        j = LBound(originalArray, 2)
        k = UBound(originalArray, 2)
        ReDim ref(j To k)
        For i = j To k
            ref(i) = i
        Next
        arrayOfColumnToReturn = ref
    End If

    ' If the caller don't pass an array for partial match
    ' check if it pass the special value 1, if true the
    ' partial match will be performed on values in columns to return
    ref = partialMatchColumnsArray
    If Not IsArray(ref) Then
        If ref = 1 Then
           partialMatchColumnsArray = arrayOfColumnToReturn
        End If
    End If

    ' use sorted column (if available) to reduce range of rows to search
    Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long
    firstRow = LBound(originalArray, 1)
    lastRow = UBound(originalArray, 1)

    Dim values As Variant, row1 As Long, row2 As Long

    If sortedColumn > -1 Then

        If IsAscendingSorted Then
           ' asc - scan down to find low, scan up to find high
           values = Array(sortedColumnLowValue, sortedColumnHighValue)
        Else
           ' desc - scan down to find high, scan up to find low
           values = Array(sortedColumnHighValue, sortedColumnLowValue)
        End If

        ' scan down
        j = LBound(originalArray, 1)
        k = UBound(originalArray, 1)
        For i = j To k
            If originalArray(i, sortedColumn) >= values(0) Then
                row1 = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        ' scan up
        For i = j To k Step -1
            If originalArray(i, sortedColumn) <= values(1) Then
                row2 = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        firstRow = IIf(IsAscendingSorted, row1, row2)
        lastRow = IIf(IsAscendingSorted, row2, row1)
    End If

    ' main loop
    Dim arKeep As Variant, KeepCount As Long
    ReDim arKeep(lastRow - firstRow + 1)
    KeepCount = 0

    Dim param(3) As Variant, p As Variant, row As Long
    param(1) = Array(firstExactMatchColumn, LCase(CStr(firstExactMatchValue)), _
                    firstColumnToExclude, LCase(CStr(firstValueToExclude)), _
                    firstColumnIsBetween, firstLowValue, firstHighValue)

    param(2) = Array(secondExactMatchColumn, LCase(CStr(secondExactMatchValue)), _
                     secondColumnToExclude, LCase(CStr(secondValueToExclude)), _
                     secondColumnIsBetween, secondLowValue, secondHighValue)

    param(3) = Array(thirdExactMatchColumn, LCase(CStr(thirdExactMatchValue)), _
                     thirdColumnToExclude, LCase(CStr(thirdValueToExclude)), _
                     thirdColumnIsBetween, thirdLowValue, thirdHighValue)

    For row = firstRow To lastRow

        ' exact, excluse and between checks
        For i = 1 To 3
            p = param(i)
            If p(0) > -1 Then If LCase(originalArray(row, p(0))) <> p(1) Then GoTo Skip
            If p(2) > -1 Then If LCase(originalArray(row, p(2))) = p(3) Then GoTo Skip
            If p(4) > -1 Then If originalArray(row, p(4) < p(5) _
                              Or originalArray(row, p(4)) > p(6)) Then GoTo Skip
        Next

        ' partial match check
        Dim col As Integer
        If IsArray(partialMatchColumnsArray) Then
            For col = LBound(partialMatchColumnsArray) To UBound(partialMatchColumnsArray)
                If InStr(1, originalArray(row, partialMatchColumnsArray(col)), partialMatchValue, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    GoTo Keep
                End If
            Next
            GoTo Skip
        End If
Keep:
        arKeep(KeepCount) = row
        KeepCount = KeepCount + 1

Skip:
    Next

    ' create results array
    Dim r, c, arCols
    Dim result As Variant
    ref = arrayOfColumnToReturn

    ReDim result(1 To KeepCount + 1, LBound(ref) + 1 To UBound(ref) + 1)

    For c = LBound(ref) To UBound(ref)
        'Debug.Print "c=", c
        For r = 1 To KeepCount
            result(r, c + 1) = originalArray(arKeep(r - 1), ref(c))
        Next
    Next
    FilterArray2 = result
    ReDim result(0)

    MsgBox "Rows to return = " & KeepCount, vbInformation, "Completed in " & Int(Timer - t0) & " secs"

End Function
```

Comment: Beautiful. Great saving of space and time. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Davide thanks, check the ReDim results line, I think KeepCount + 1 should just be KeepCount otherwise you get an empty row at the bottom.